# How to determine size of cell layout for ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

How do I figure out what the height and width of my ListView item cell is? After I inflate it, getHeight() and getWidth() both return 0.

When I inflate my cell layout xml in my list adapter's getView(), the height and width of the view is still (0,0). I'm assuming the size of the cell and its subviews won't be set until after I return the cell and it gets automatically added to the ListView. So, how/when/where can I get the real size information for my view and its children?

Each row in my ListView has 4 TextViews which form columns in the ListView. I need to dynamically determine the best fittable font size so that all of the numbers in my TextViews will fit. In other words, if I need to use a textSize of 16 in order to fit the largest string into it's TextView, then I want all 4 TextViews in every row to use textSize=16.

I'm preprocessing all of my data to find the longest strings, I just need to find out how big each of my TextViews are in the ListView rows... but when I'm inflating them in getView(), the row and the children in the row have height/width of (0,0).

How do I figure out what the height and width of my ListView item cell is so I can determine the right font size?

Answer (score 1):

Inflate a layout doing not immediately. This process need a some time. Inflate task stored in internal queue and need time to push out from internal queue.

Try to use a [TextView.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method. Then you can get real View size asynchronously, some time later. The Runnable implementation will be run in UI thread.